# Rails db:migrate with postgres running in a container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

In my dev env I have postgres running in a container, running db:migrate worked fine until recently I needed to change the schema to sql

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Not when I run db:migrate I get the following error:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "mydatabase" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myuser"
```

Looks to me that pg_dump ignores the database.yml settings. Anyone else had any luck with this kind of setup?

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing is install postgresql-client-common and postgresql-client, in ubuntu you use:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-client-common postgresql-client
```

This gave me pg_dump locally, then I've opened a terminal in the docker machine and add `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust` to the default pg_hba.conf file

To open a shell use:

```
docker exec -i -t <idOfContainer> /bin/bash
```

To add the line:

```
cd /var/lib/postgresql/data
echo host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust >> pg_hba.conf
```

The last step is that you will need to add your local user to postgress, pg_dump will not use the credential from datbaase.yml so you should connect to psql and run:

```
CREATE USER <youruser>
```